# Need assign List object parsed from JSON file to a object property

Tags: c#

I trying to build Magic The Gathering card viewer and getting data from json. I  have created json file, then copy all and paste special to my class to generate a model. In constructor using json parser I parsed object fine, but when I try to assign to that object property, so I can make method retrieve all cards. But when I trying to do that it says that I can't implicitly assign. I try to assign Cards = cardsCollection; that where it throws an error.

```
namespace MTGArena
{
    public class Cards
    {
```

`public class Rootobject
    {


        static Rootobject()
        {
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("cards.json"))
            {
                string json = file.ReadToEnd();
                Rootobject cardsCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
                Cards = cardsCollection;


            }
        }


        public static List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

        public static List<Card> GetCards()
        {
            return Cards;
        }


    }
}

public class Card
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string set { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string[] cost { get; set; }
    public int cmc { get; set; }
    public string rarity { get; set; }
    public string cid { get; set; }
    public int?[] frame { get; set; }
    public string artist { get; set; }
    public string dfc { get; set; }
    public bool collectible { get; set; }
    public bool craftable { get; set; }
    public int dfcId { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public string grpId { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public string small { get; set; }
    public string normal { get; set; }
    public string large { get; set; }
    public string art_crop { get; set; }
}`

}

Comment: hmmm I guess you want Cards = RootObject.Cards

Comment: You could save yourself some pain and leverage this great resource: https://mtgjson.com/

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
Rootobject cardsCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

for:

```
var cardsCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Card>>(json);
```

Comment: This makes sense.  Of course the json needs to be created correctly too.

Comment: Well yes, if json is not correct actually nothing will work unless you sanitize the file first...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below syntax

```
IList<Card> cards  = cardsCollection;
```

dont create empty `Cards` class. It has no use